# Service Client does not map inherited members

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, service

**The Service:**

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Request
{
    public abstract void CopyFrom(Request request);
}

[DataContract]
public class RealRequest : Request
{
    public void CopyFrom(Request request)
    {
        {...}
    }
}
```

**The Consumer:**

I add the Service Reference and when I try to compile the Consumer:

> 'Bla.RealRequest' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   'Service.Request.CopyFrom(Service.Request)'

It is implemented though. I dont want to replicate the implementation in the Service Reference. Is there any way to fix this?

I should probably also say that the Request is in another project. But I dont see how'd that interfere. Also, though the error is with Bla.RealRequest, the class is in Service.RealRequest, the mapping of the class in Bla is the one that doesnt include the inherited method.

Comment: that doesn't seem right....  anything else weird?

Comment: I should probably also say that the Request is in another project. But I dont see how'd that interfere. Also, though the error is with Bla.RealRequest, the class is in Service.RealRequest, the mapping of the class in Bla is the one that doesnt include the inherited method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me you're missing the override keyword?

```
[DataContract]
public class RealRequest : Request
{
    public override void CopyFrom(Request request)
    {
        {...}
    }
}
```